# WordPress - Woocommerce товары в авторизированном виде и в режиме гостя

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Как сделать так, чтобы человек не заходя в свой аккаунт на wordpress, имел возможность добавить в корзину товары (не в авторизированном виде), потом заходил в аккаунт и добавлял еще товары, но как только выходил из аккаунта, то товары автоматически возвращались в первоначальное значение, до захода в аккаунт?

На сайте стоит WooCommerce.

Comment: Что значит "автоматически возвращались в первоначальное значение, до захода в аккаунт"?

Comment: До захода в аккаунт.

Comment: С товарами в корзине?

Comment: Нужно вернуть значение ДО захода в аккаунт. У тебя было 3 определённых товаров, когда ты был не авторизован. Ты зашёл в аккаунт, положил ещё товары, вышел и должны вернуться те 3.